# Can you make the id field the external id in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I have the id field on a netsuite object. Can I change use the id column as the external id in Netsuite, something like in Salesforce?

Comment: I would advise against using the native "internalid" field on NetSuite records as the external id.  The only reason why is because most of the "internalid" values are system generated and read only/cannot be influenced by users.  You could create a script deployed to several record types or scheduled to run that takes the internal id and copies it into the external id (or custom) field...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can definitely write a user event script to populate the internal id of any record to it's external ID field. The "externalid" field is exposed via SuiteScript or via csv import
- The internal id is a unique auto-generated number which identifies a unique NetSuite record and hence the sequence would change if deletion/inactivation happens For eg.if there are records with internal Ids 1, 2 and 3 in system and 2 gets deleted, then IDs that remain in the system are 1 and 3. User does not have the ability to alter these internal Ids since they are system generated. Hence, they cannot be customized (acc to developer's preference) specially if you want to follow a specific convention.
- External Id should contain a value which should be unique across multiple integrated systems.Eg. SFDC (Salesforce). The recommended way is to write an afer submit user event script to populate external ID on all the integrated records and keep these synced in both systems

Here is a sample code in SuiteScript 2.0 which populated external ids for subsidiary, account and department:

```js
var recordType = context.newRecord.type;
            log.debug({ title: 'Record Type', details: recordType })
        
            var recordId = context.newRecord.id;
            log.debug({ title: 'Record ID', details: recordId })
        
            var rec = record.load({
                                    type: recordType,
                                    id: recordId
                                });
                                
            //Setting External ID on subsidiary
            if (recordType == record.Type.SUBSIDIARY) 
               {
            var subExID 
         =rec.setValue('externalid'(rec.getValue('tranprefix').substring(0, 3)))
                log.debug({ title: 'TranPrefix', details: subExID })
                }
        
            //Setting External ID on account
            if (recordType == record.Type.ACCOUNT) 
            {
            var accExID = rec.setValue('externalid', 
     rec.getValue('acctnumber'))
            log.debug({ title: 'External ID', details: accExID })
                                }
        
            //Setting External ID on department
            if (recordType == record.Type.DEPARTMENT) 
            {
            var deptExID = rec.setValue('externalid', rec.getValue('custrecord_dept_code'))
            log.debug({ title: 'External ID', details: deptExID })
            }
```

Please let me know if this is helpful !!!